# How to watch for changes in collection objects inside custom collection

Tags: c#, sorting, generics, collections, inotifypropertychanged

I am making a custom collection that is based off a list, its purpose is to be Observable,Prevent Duplicates,Sorted etc.

I have an add method like so :

```
    public class SortedObservableCollection<T> : List<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public void Add(T item)
        {
            base.Add(item);
            base.Sort();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
            this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);
        }
}
```

But somehow when the object is directly changed inside the collection I need an automatic resort to happen, or for the collection to be notified so it can do a sort again.

Like :

```
SortedObservableCollection<IRCUser> users = new SortedObservableCollection<IRCUser>();
users.Add(new IRCUser { Nick = "User1", Status = IRCUserStatus.Unknown });
users.Add(new IRCUser { Nick = "User2", Status = IRCUserStatus.Unknown });
users.Add(new IRCUser { Nick = "User3", Status = IRCUserStatus.Unknown });


users.Single(x => x.Nick == "User3").Nick = "User11";
```

The User3 stays at the bottom of the collection, please note I am using my own IComparable implementation and its not just an alphabetical sort.

I need the collection to catch this change and notify me so I can do something.

I know I will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the objects, but what I am unsure about is how will the collection catch that, the only way I can see is if on the add method I do :

```
item.PropertyChanged += (o,e) { ..check then... base.Sort(); };
```

But if I have 10,000 users is this the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

the item class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` 
then you have two options: 
save the list (parent) in the child class (item) and on item propertychange you call a certain method

or when you add an item to your list you add its NotifyPropertyChanged Event. I would go that way.

List:

```
public listclass()
{
  this.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(listclass_ListChanged);
}    

void listclass_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded)
  {
    item item = this[e.NewIndex];
    item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Item_PropertyChanged);
  }
}

void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.PropertyName == "propertyname")
   {

   }     
}
```

item implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public item()
{      
  this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(AnyPropertyChanged); 
}

private void AnyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // example how to use
  if (e.PropertyName == "anyproperyname")
  {

  }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}

private Boolean bTheProperty = true;
public Boolean TheProperty
{
   get { return bTheProperty ; }
   set 
   { 
     if (bTheProperty != value) 
     { 
       bTheProperty = value; 
       InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TheProperty")); 
     }           
   }
}
```

on some list you have to set this property to true, so it fires the listchanged event:

```
this.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
```

if you dont wanna use the property changed events you could go this dirty way:

```
private list oParent

public item(list parent)
{
  this.oParent = parent;
}

private string sName;
public string Name
{
   get { return sName; }
   set 
   { 
     if (sName!= value) 
     { 
       sName= value; 
       if(this.parent != null)
       {  
         this.parent.IsSorted = false; 
       }
     }           
   }
}
```

then you can use a timer in list class and check if isSorted is false, or invoke a propertychanged on list.IsSorted property.

Comment: I think you are basically implementing what I was thinking (a handler for each object in the list).

Answer (score 0):

As I thought it seems the solution is to add a listener to every object in the collection, and remove it when the item is removed. I can implement that like so :

```
public class SortedObservableList<T> : List<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged where T : INotifyPropertyChanged, IComparable<T>
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        base.Sort();
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += InnerObjectChanged;
    }

    private void InnerObjectChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Sort();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged -= InnerObjectChanged;
        bool result = base.Remove(item);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item);
        return result;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            this.CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

**IRCUser**

```
    public class IRCUser : IComparable<IRCUser>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _nick;
        public string Nick
        {
            get
            {
                return _nick;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _nick)
                {
                    ...
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public int CompareTo(IRCUser other)
        {
...
        }


        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I have just tested this, it seems to work.